# How do I get the multiplication of a property in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I've a `List<T>` that have a property called `Odds` of type `decimal`, how can I get the *multiplication* of amount?

Usually for elaborate the `Sum` I did something like this:

```
decimal amount = myList.Sum(x => x.Odds);
```

but I cannot find any property the allow me to get the *multiplication*. Is not possible over linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Aggregate` (i.e. *aggregate* all items in the collection by multipling them):

```
  decimal amount = myList.Aggregate((s, a) => s * a.Odds);
```

Comment: You can wrap this solution to extension method `ProductOf` (for example). And have nice and readable code: `decimal amount = myList.ProductOf(item => item.Odds);`

Comment: @Fabio yes, reading the doc I learn that if the object is complex you can do something like this: `myList.Select(c => c.Odds).Aggregate((decimal s, decimal a) => s * a);`